# How to send (or upload ) images from flutter app to Django server and vice versa?

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, file-upload

I want just the big picture on how to upload an image from a flutter app (.jpg or .png formats) to a Django server in order to classify the image and return a response, also how to send an from the server when the user in flutter app make a get request (I want just guidelines).

I didn't tried yet because I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `image_picker` package to allow users to select an image from their device's gallery or camera.

Import the http package and create a MultipartFile object from the selected image file.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<http.MultipartRequest> createMultipartRequest(String url, File image) async {
  final request = http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST',
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image.path));
  return request;
}
```

Use the http package to send the multipart request to your Django server's endpoint.
Process the server's response (e.g., image classification result) and display it in the Flutter app.

```
Future<String?> uploadImage(String url, File image) async {


final request = await createMultipartRequest(url, image);
  final streamedResponse = await request.send();
  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body); // Parse response if using JSON
    return responseData['classification_result']; // Example assuming JSON response
  } else {
    print('Error: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    return null;
  }
}

// Usage
void onUploadButtonPressed() async {
  final imageFile = await pickImage();
  if (imageFile != null) {
    final result = await uploadImage('http://your-server-address/upload', imageFile);
    if (result != null) {
      // Display classification result (e.g., in a Text widget)
    } else {
      // Handle upload error
    }
  }
}
```

To upload an image from a Flutter app to a Django server, you can follow these steps:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
  var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST', Uri.parse('http://your-django-server.com/upload_image_endpoint'));
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path));

  var response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Image uploaded successfully');
  } else {
    print('Failed to upload image: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
  }
}
```

Comment: it was very helpful, thank you. Can you tell me how to send the image from the Django server to the flutter app ?

Comment: You can use uploadImage function as above